# Why TypeScript cannot find defined constants?

Tags: typescript

I have a simple piece like this:

```
const getMethod = 'get';
const postMethod = 'post';

export type RequestMethod = getMethod | postMethod;
```

In [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20getMethod%20%3D%20'get'%3B%0D%0Aconst%20postMethod%20%3D%20'post'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20RequestMethod%20%3D%20getMethod%20%7C%20postMethod%3B) it shows an error that it cannot find `getMethod` and `postMethod` constants, though shows a compiled version on the right side.

What is wrong with this code? I used to consume it like this before but now it shows an error.

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

As per the [spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.4) a union type is a union of two types. Constants are not types. String literals are types, again as per the [spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.2.9), that is why you can write 'get' | 'post'.

You could use the type of the constant which will be the string literal type:

```
const getMethod = 'get';
const postMethod = 'post';

export type RequestMethod = typeof getMethod | typeof postMethod;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to use constants as types.

If you want `RequestMethod` to be a union type, you must define `getMethod` and `postMethod` as types instead.

```
type getMethod = 'get';
type postMethod = 'post';

export type RequestMethod = getMethod | postMethod;
```

Comment: I'm guessing he defined the constants because he want to be able to use the values in code, and wants to avoid having to write the string again.

Answer (score 0):

`getMethod` is expected to be an `type | interface | enum`, etc. not a variable.

You can try:

```
type getMethod = 'get';
type postMethod = 'post';

export type RequestMethod = getMethod | postMethod;
```

or

```
enum RequestMethod { 
    GET = 'get',
    POST = 'post' 
}

const getMethod = RequestMethod.GET;

function makeRequest(method: RequestMethod) {

}
```